# Can I Convert a Index.cshtml in asp.net MVC to PDF using html2pdf?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, model-view-controller, converters, html2pdf

I am facing a problem in converting a view in asp.net MVC to PDF using html2pdf library and jquery,
so please can anyone help ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please write out with as much detail as possible the error messages and the most relevant part of the source code you might be having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rotativa, it's seems good
Rotativa is an open source package which uses the web kit engine which is used by Chrome browser to render the HTML. Most of the HTML tags and styles are supported by this framework.
it contains many classes you can use to convert to pdf like :

- ActionAsPdf
- PartialViewAsPdf
- UrlAsPdf
- ViewAsPdf
  for example

```
    <div style="text-align:right">@Html.ActionLink("Print Employee", 
    "PrintEmployee", new { id=Model.ID })</div>  

    public ActionResult PrintEmployee(int id)  
    {  
      var report = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Employee", new { id=id });  
      return report;  
    }
```